# Desktop GUI of Raspberry Pi B+ is not working?

Tags: raspbian, gui, desktop

I am facing this issue after I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo
```

and reboot the RPI. actually, I developed some GUI on the RPI and whenever I run it face this error **libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate in RPI**, so I looked for a solution and tried the above commands. after rebooting my RPI is automatically logged into RPI and GUI is not showing only Command line is available.

**Tried solution**

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and in > system Options have select > S5 Boot/AutoLogin > B4 desktop login Desktop GUI, automaticslly..
but nothing happened, Gui is not initiated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rebooting after making the GUI change?

Comment: yes, many times.

Comment: your question is about Linux, not about Raspberry Pi

Comment: how? i am running rpi with desktop screen?